# Make a clickable element close a visible element before opening a new element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**See my code snippet below.** I have multiple clickable divs that when clicked, shows some content below. Each clickable div displays a different set of content. My problem is, both content blocks can be open at the same time. I only want to show **one content block at a time**. So when clicked, if there is already a content block open I want it to close before opening the new content block. How can I achieve this?

```js
function showOne() {
  var x = document.getElementById("thing");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function showTwo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("another-thing");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div{
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.clickone{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clicktwo{
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thing,
.another-thing{
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="clickone" onclick="showOne()">
    <p>Click Me To Show One Thing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="clicktwo" onclick="showTwo()">
    <p>Click Me To Show Another Thing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="thing" class="thing">
    <p>Thing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="another-thing" class="another-thing">
    <p>Another Thing</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be making a switch like this:

```js
function showOne() {
  var x = document.getElementById("thing");
  var another = document.getElementById("another-thing");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    another.style.display = "none"
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function showTwo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("another-thing");
  var thing = document.getElementById("thing");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    thing.style.display = "none";
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div{
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.clickone{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clicktwo{
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thing,
.another-thing{
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="clickone" onclick="showOne()">
    <p>Click Me To Show One Thing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="clicktwo" onclick="showTwo()">
    <p>Click Me To Show Another Thing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="thing" class="thing">
    <p>Thing</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="another-thing" class="another-thing">
    <p>Another Thing</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

But you can make it more reusable doing a reusable function
Its better if you have more and more div's to switch

```js
function show(receivedId) {
  const allIds = ["thing", "another-thing"];

  for (const index in allIds) {
    const actualId = allIds[index];
    if (actualId === receivedId) {
      document.getElementById(actualId).style.display = "flex";
    } else {
      document.getElementById(actualId).style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

div{
  background-color: teal;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.clickone{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clicktwo{
  background-color: CadetBlue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.thing,
.another-thing{
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 25px;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="clickone" onclick="show('thing')">
    <p>Click Me To Show One Thing</p>
  </div>

  <div class="clicktwo" onclick="show('another-thing')">
    <p>Click Me To Show Another Thing</p>
  </div>

  <div id="thing" class="thing">
    <p>Thing</p>
  </div>

  <div id="another-thing" class="another-thing">
    <p>Another Thing</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your second answer works great! However, it no longer toggles on an off when you click the same element. What should be added to bring that back?

Answer (score 0):

```
function showOne() {
  var x = document.getElementById("thing");
  var y = document.getElementById("another-thing");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function showTwo() {
  var x = document.getElementById("another-thing");
  var y = document.getElementById("thing");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "flex";
    y.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

If there are only two divs in question you could do it like this. If there are many then perhaps give them class names as well as IDs and then cycle through the class names before setting the 1 ID you wish to show.

Comment: You may wish to add `y.style.display = "none"` to the `else` statement for each function if you'd like the divs which haven't been selected to disappear too.